# Create a Fork From GitHub with PyCharm

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, pycharm

Is there a way to create a fork from GitHub repository using PyCharm's built in version control tools?

I want to do the equivalent of

```
git clone git@github.com:your-user-name/pandas.git pandas-yourname
cd pandas-yourname
git remote add upstream git://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git
```

I can do just about everything else from with PyCharm, so it would be nice to be able to fork from there too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single command to achieve this.
Here is request to add such - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-108313

However, you could clone a project using VCS - Checkout from Version Control - Git and add the remote called "upstream" using VCS - Git - Remotes...